# How do i incorporate ADT into this program

Tags: java, methods, adt

I have a task to write a program that takes in a profit score and multiplies it by 2, takes hard work score and multiplies it by 5, adds the two together, divides by 7 and then multiplies by 5000 to give a "bonus".

This would be very simple but the specification states i must use at least 9 methods not including main, use functions and getter/setter methods. The rest i can do but i don't know how to use ADT in a program like this.

This is what i've got so far...it does what its supposed to but its missing ADT.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

class bonus {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       int i1 = inputProfit();
       int w1 = inputWork();
       int p1 = performanceScore(i1, w1);
       int f1 = finalbonus(p1);
       output(f1);

        System.exit(0);
    }//end main method

    public static int inputProfit() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Profit score?");
        int profitScore = scanner.nextInt();
        return profitScore;

    }

    public static int inputWork() {
        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Hard work score?");
        int workScore = scanner1.nextInt();
        return workScore;
    }

    public static int profit(int profitScore) {
        profitScore = profitScore*2;
        return profitScore;
    }

    public static int work(int workScore) {
        workScore = workScore*5;
        return workScore;
    }

    public static int performanceScore(int profitScore, int workScore) {
        int p = profit(profitScore);
        int w = work(workScore);
        int performance = ((p + w)/7);
        return performance;
    }

    public static int finalbonus(int performance) {
        int payOut = performance * 5000 ;
        return payOut;
    }

    public static void output(int payOut) {
        System.out.println("Your bonus is " + payOut + " pounds");
    }


}//end class bonus
```

Comment: What do you mean by "ADT"? How is it supposed to be "integrated"?

Comment: adt = abstract data type? I think the assignment is to create a class with getter/setter methods with some helper methods to do the calculations.

Comment: Yes, abstract data types. I dont know how to use them-wanted to know briefly how i could use them in a program like this.